# new sonarqube(docker) can't connect to existing database that was serving old sonarqube (server)

Tags: mysql, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

We installed sonarqube version 6.7(33306) on centos7.2 server with mysql 5.6 database.  Its working for 3 months now and has data we need to preserve.

We want it on Kubernetes/Docker > I configured the official sonarqube docker image 6.7(33306) to connect to a new mysql5.6 database.  works but the db is empty.

Now I need my real data/db working with the new dockered sonarqube.  I dumped the existing DB and imported it on the new DB that dockered sonarqube connects to.   Now when I try to connect from the docker image to the new db I get this error.

> SonarQube Server / 6.7.0.33306 /
>   5d031d9d2ac3f69b4b9bc600d50563b1886c7d8b
>
> INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for
>   jdbc:mysql://192.168.27.104:3407/sonarqube?
>   useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&autoReconnect=true
>
> INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home:
>   /opt/sonarqube
>
> INFO  web[][o.s.s.u.SystemPasscodeImpl] System authentication by
>   passcode is disabled
>
> ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Web server startup failed: Current
>   version is too old. Please upgrade to Long Term Support version
>   firstly.

Both sonarqubes are the same version and the original was not upgraded from an older version.

Ive tried the latest sonarqube docker with the tag lts, its the same error.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/server/sonar-server/src/main/java/org/sonar/server/platform/DatabaseServerCompatibility.java) and [this](https://github.com/alip/sonar/blob/master/sonar-core/src/main/java/org/sonar/core/persistence/DatabaseVersion.java) SonarQube source code. The SonarQube instance and the database must be in sync.

Comment: This is solved !!! thanks for help from Simon Brandhof.   He identify that the schema in the DB for the new dockered sonarqube relates to a version lower than SonarQube 5.6.  This sql select showed us the truth >   "select * from schema_migrations".  This proved that the database restore was not the right one.  Obtained the correct mysql dump from the correct Sonarqube 6.7 database.    I now have a working dockered sonarqube 6/7 with all the projects and data I needed over there.   The database schema I was using had been created by an installation of SonarQube that is "too old", less than 5.6